# Excel VBA color cells when its value is equal to values in array

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched for examples and tried many different codes, but it's not working. 
I would like to create a macro, which goes through 2 sheets in the same workbook (one called "Submission", the second called "PASTfromFeb2017"). In each sheet I would like to check if value is equal to those listed in array. If the value is equal, the whole cell should be filled with color (for ex. red).

Here is what I have so far (but it doesn't work)...

```
Option Explicit
Sub colorCell()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim SubmissionWkst As Worksheet
Dim PASTfromFeb2017Wkst As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim sheetName As String
Dim arrSht() As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim k As Long
Dim i As Integer


arrSht = Array("MK-3475", "MK-8415", "MK-0431", "MK-0517", "MK-8931", "MK-8835", "V-501", "V-503", "V-110", "MK-4305", "V-211", "MK-5172")

For k = LBound(arrSht) To UBound(arrSht)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Submission").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
        For lRow = 2 To lastRow
            If Cells(lRow, "C").Value Like arrSht.Value Then
            Cells(lRow, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next i
   End With
Next k

For k = LBound(arrSht) To UBound(arrSht)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PASTfromFeb2017").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
        For lRow = 2 To lastRow
            If Cells(lRow, "C").Value Like arrSht.Value Then
            Range(Cells(lRow, "C"), Cells(lRow, "C")).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next i
   End With
Next k
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `Like` and not `=`? Do the cells contain more than just `MK-3475` for example?

Comment: I tried = but it doesn't work. I am very new in VBA.

Comment: Much to say. First I noticed that `For lRow` seems to be closed out by `Next i` on both occasions. Fix that. Also while ActiveSheet should work , it is usually unnecessary, and the effect can be better achieved by EXPLICIT sheet referencing. Also you could do both at the same time

Comment: `k` variable isnt used why ? do you intend to use it in `arrSht(k).Value` ?

Comment: Also lastRow is not set anywhere. Then it will be 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your `For` loops, and use the `Application.Match` to find if a possible cell in column "C" equals one of the values inside `arrSht` array.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub colorCell()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim SubmissionWkst As Worksheet
Dim PASTfromFeb2017Wkst As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim arrSht() As Variant
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

arrSht = Array("MK-3475", "MK-8415", "MK-0431", "MK-0517", "MK-8931", "MK-8835", "V-501", "V-503", "V-110", "MK-4305", "V-211", "MK-5172")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws
        ' run the code only if sheet's name equal one of the tow in the If
        If .Name = "Submission" Or .Name = "PASTfromFeb2017" Then
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To lastRow
                ' check that there is a match with one of the values inside arrSht array
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("C" & i).Value, arrSht, 0)) Then
                    .Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @A.S.H  LOL, true, maybe the PO has future plan for them, I removed a few unneeded ones

Comment: Thank you very much Shai Rado! This macro works great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It uses `.Find` which is a bit more efficient:

```
Sub ColorCell()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Submission").Range("C2:C" & Worksheets("Submission").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("PASTfromFeb2017").Range("C2:C" & Worksheets("PASTfromFeb2017").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)

    FindMatches rng1
    FindMatches rng2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub FindMatches(rng As Range)
    Dim arrSht() As Variant, c As Range, n As Integer

    arrSht = Array("MK-3475", "MK-8415", "MK-0431", "MK-0517", "MK-8931", "MK-8835", "V-501", "V-503", "V-110", "MK-4305", "V-211", "MK-5172")

    For n = LBound(arrSht) To UBound(arrSht)

        With rng
            Set c = .Find(arrSht(n), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End With

    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both solutions are great!